# How do I change the scope of the service worker sw.js

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I'm using react/redux and express to deliver a server side rendered application over a HTTPS connection.

My service worker code in the sw.js file located in the /build/assets folder is

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/assets/sw.js', { scope: '/' }).then((registration) => {
            console.log('SW registered: ', registration);
        }).catch((registrationError) => {
            console.log('SW registration failed: ', registrationError);
        });
    });
}
```

The assets folder is served for my application but I want to change the scope of the service worker to root i.e. `/`.

So in express I'm adding the custom header as follows:

`res.setHeader('Service-Worker-Allowed', '/');`

But I'm still getting the following error:

```
The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/assets/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.
```

Am I adding the header in correct place? Do I need to do something more?

Please leave a comment if any more info is required.

Any help regarding the solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which requests get the `res.setHeader('Service-Worker-Allowed', '/');` added to them? Your HTML requests, or your `/assets/sw.js` requests?

Comment: The header is being added to the html document only, not on the sw.js request. Is this where the issue is? How do I add the header to the particular request.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution after Jeff Posnick's comment. I'm posting this in case someone else gets stuck and needs a little help.

The header has to be set on the service worker file specifically instead of the root document.

To do this in express:

```
const options = {
    setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
        res.set('Service-Worker-Allowed', '/');
    },
};

app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), './build/public'), options));
```